# The coproducts $\mathbb{C}_q[U] \to \mathbb{C}_q[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[U]$ and $\mathbb{C}[U] \to \mathbb{C}[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}[U]$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

A coproduct $\varphi: \mathbb{C}_q[U] \to \mathbb{C}_q[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}_q[U]$ is given by: $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$, where $x$ is a generator of $\mathbb{C}_q[U]$. There is a coproduct $\mathbb{C}[U] \to \mathbb{C}[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}[U]$ which is the pull-back of the multiplication map: $U \times U \to U$. The coproduct  $\psi: \mathbb{C}[U] \to \mathbb{C}[U] \otimes \mathbb{C}[U]$ is given by: $x_{ik} \mapsto \sum_{j} x_{ij} \otimes x_{jk}$.

Are there some relation between the map $\varphi$ and the map $\psi$? Thank you very much.

Edit: $U$ is the group of unipotent upper triangular matrices.

Comment: What is $U$?  The group of unipotent upper triangular matrices?

Comment: @Joel, thank you very much. Yes, $U$ is the group of unipotent upper triangular matrices.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}_q[U]$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebra $ \mathbb{C}[U] $ is a polynomial ring on generators $ x_{ij} $ where $ i < j $.  The coproduct is given (as you say) by $ \psi(x_{ik})= \sum_j x_{ij} \otimes x_{jk} $ where where interpret $ x_{ij} = 0 $ if $ i > j $ and $ x_{ii} = 1 $.  In particular, we see that 
$$
\psi(x_{i i+1})= 1 \otimes x_{i i+1} + x_{i i+1} \otimes 1.
$$
Of course, these $ x_{i i+1} $ do not generate $ \mathbb{C}[U] $, since they are only some of the generators of this polynomial ring.

However, when we move to the quantization $ \mathbb{C}_q[U] $, then $ x_{i i+1} $ are now generators of this non-commutative algebra and as you say $ \phi(x_{i i+1}) =  1 \otimes x_{i i+1} + x_{i i+1} \otimes 1$.  So we see that $ \phi $ and $ \psi $ do agree on these elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit ? What is $\mathbb{C}_q[U]$ ? or give reference. Thank you in advance.